# Drupal 7 - Is it possible to attach an existing file to a newly created node?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Trying to create a node and attach an existing fine in Drupal-7.

I have spent quite a lot of time to attach an existing file at server side to a newly created node.
I googled quite a bit, almost everywhere the examples are there for file upload / save and then attach to a node.
Did not get any documentation thats says how to attach an existing file to a newly created node.

At a high level, my code is as below.

```
 $node = new stdClass();
 $node->type = resume' ;  // a new content type created
 node_object_prepare($node);
 $node->title = My title';
 $node->language = 'en'; 
 $node->uid = 1; 
 $file_obj = file_load($fid); 
 $node->field_resume[$node->language][0] = (array)$file_obj; //field_resume is the   machine name for file field
 node_save($node);
```

Can somebody please let me know what I am missing here?
The new node is created, with no attachment.
How can I get the file to attached to node.

Comment: Does the node is inserted and the file field is left blank?! or nothing is inserted at all ?!

Comment: Yes, Node is created with no file attached.

Answer (score 1):

Normally this should work, kindly try to add the following line and tell me if it works

```
$node = new stdClass();
$node->is_new = TRUE; // This is the line I added.
// Your code continues as is...
```

Hope this works... Muhammad.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Did not work. Node is created without attachment.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't done this myself, but found a [link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29416/programmatically-setting-an-image-field-from-hook-node-insert-drupal-7) where the following is done:

```
$node->field_resume[$node->language][0]['fid'] = $fid;
```

The difference from your code is that the above piece of code simply just sets the $fid. Not sure if it works, but you could give it a try.

Furthermore, you might want to invoke [file_usage_add()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_usage_add/7) to let Drupal know that the node now keeps a reference to that file.

Comment: Still not able to create node with attachment. Thanks for introducing me to file_usage_add() function , indeed it is very useful.